# laravel collective not working with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am working on laravel 5.4 and using laravel collective 5.1 but i when i try to update the composer i am facing this error

```
>  composer update Loading composer repositories with package
> information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
> requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> 
>   Problem 1
>     - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.36
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.20
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.19
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.18
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.17
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.16
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.15
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.14
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.13   
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.6
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1
>     - laravelcollective/html v5.1.0 requires illuminate/session 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6,
> v5.1.8].   
>     - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
>     - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
>     - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
>     - don't install illuminate/session v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
>     - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12,
> v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2,
> v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8,
> v5.4.9].
>     - Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.2,
> v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9].
```

This is how my Composer.json looks

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
```

Can someone help me out to solve this

thanks

Comment: Update: `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` to `"laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",` and then try `composer update`

Comment: @HirenGohel thanks for your answer but still the error is same

Comment: See, first change the name of `vendor` folder to `vendor_old` and then remove `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` from `composer.json` file. Then run `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"` and after that run `composer update` command. This will generate new vendor folder with new dependencies! Hope this will helps you!

Comment: @hirenGohel Thanks alot, it is Fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First change the name of `vendor` folder to `vendor_old` and then remove `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` from `composer.json` file.

Then run `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"` and after that run `composer update` command.

This will generate new `vendor` folder with new dependencies!

Hope this will helps you!